# DISM: "The source files could not be found and download failed"

Tags: windows-server-2012, dism

Trying to install a selection of IIS Windows features via [dism](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825236.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
dism /NoRestart /ONLINE /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:IIS
-ASPNET /FeatureName:IIS-NetFxExtensibility /FeatureName:WCF-HTTP-Activation
```

gives the error

> Error: 0x800f0906
>
> The source files could not be downloaded. Use the "source" option to
>   specify the location of the files that are required t o restore the
>   feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see 
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.
>
> The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The features `IIS-NetFxExtensibility`, `IIS-ASPNET` and `IIS-NetFxExtensibility` are for .NET 3.5 and are restricted for security reasons.

I really wanted .NET 4.5 anyway, so fixed by appending `45` to those feature names

```
dism /NoRestart /ONLINE /Enable-Feature /All  /FeatureName:IIS
-ASPNET45 /FeatureName:IIS-NetFxExtensibility45 /FeatureName:WCF-HTTP-Activation /FeatureName:WCF-HTTP-Activation45
```

Comment: To do the equivalent in chef, instead of `include_recipe 'iis::mod_aspnet'`, use  `include_recipe 'iis::mod_aspnet45'`